# "was" or "were" in the context of "X wishes that he [was / were] Y"

Tags: tenses, subjunctive-mood, mood

If you are saying that somebody wishes that they could have been somebody else, which would be more correct:

E from the eels wishes he **was** Elliott Smith

or

E from the eels wishes he **were** Elliott Smith?

Comment: Sounds familiar -- have you checked previous questions for a possible duplicate?

Comment: I did, though I wasn't exactly sure if this fit under the subjunctive moood or not.

Answer (score 1):

Since E is not Elliott Smith (and never will be), it is appropriate to use the [subjunctive mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive) ("were").

Answer (score 1):

I quote from *The American Heritage Dictionary* (Fifth Edition). The quote settles the question adequately.

> A traditional rule requires the use of *were* rather than *was* in a contrary-to-fact statement that follows 'wish': "I wish I **were** (not *was*) lighter on my feet." While many people do insist on upholding this rule, the indicative *was* in such clauses can be found in the works of many well-known writers.